# I cannot seem to .setText more than twice

Tags: java, methods, label, actionlistener

I am currently making a quiz game. I have managed to set the game up as follows -

1. The user clicks the start button.
2. From here this opens a text file and retrieves each question and saves them to a string.
3. It then adds these strings to an Arraylist.
4. I then have display the first element of the array to a Label (this is the first question).
5. From here I have managed to make a method that checks the label text and set the text of 4 buttons to 4 different buttons.
6. If the user selects the correct answer it adds +1 to a score integer and then moves onto the next `question(askQues2();)`. If the user selects the wrong answer it just moves on to the next `question(askQues2();)`.
7. Once it starts the next question`(askQues2();)` it changes all of the values that I have told it to. *i.e* LabelQuestion and the 4 different answer buttons.
8. If the user selects the correct answer it adds +1 to a score integer and then moves onto the next `question(askQues3();)`.

**THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS**

When I chose an answer during the second question, it does not run the 3rd question method.

**CODE**

```
   public void askQues1 (){
       String askQues1 = questions.get(0);
       LabelQuestion.setText(askQues1);
       ButAnsA.setText("Gillard");
       ButAnsB.setText("Howard");
       ButAnsC.setText("Rudd");
       ButAnsD.setText("Abbott");

       ButAnsA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
           Score += 1;             
           askQues2();
       }   
       });
       ButAnsB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){           
           askQues2();
       }   
       });
       ButAnsC.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){           
           askQues2();
       }   
       });
       ButAnsD.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){            
           askQues2();
       }   
       });


   }
   public void askQues2(){
       String askQues2 = questions.get(1);
       LabelQuestion.setText(askQues2);
       ButAnsA.setText("1999");
       ButAnsB.setText("2004");
       ButAnsC.setText("2007");
       ButAnsD.setText("2010");  

       ButAnsA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){              
           askQues3();
       }   
       });
       ButAnsA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){              
           askQues3();
       }   
       });
       ButAnsA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){              
           askQues3();
       }   
       });
       ButAnsA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
           Score += 1;
           askQues3();
       }   
       });
   }
   public void askQues3(){
       String askQues3 = questions.get(2);
       LabelQuestion.setText(askQues3);
       ButAnsA.setText("Broncos");
       ButAnsB.setText("Knights");
       ButAnsC.setText("Storm");
       ButAnsD.setText("Dragons");                                              
   }
```

**I can tell that it does not load the 3rd method because the question label or answer buttons change.**

I have tried multiple options that I have found on the internet. None of them have fixed this problem.

If you require more information. Please let me know. Like I said it is my first time posting a question so I 'm not familiar with standards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding `actionListener` to the buttons. I don't think a button can detect more than 2 actions judging by your problem.

Try setting an `onClickListener()` to the buttons instead.

Code:

```
ButAnsA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            askQues3();
        }
      });
```

NOTE: There's a difference between `adding` and `setting` listeners. By `setting` a listener every time, you're only replacing the previous one. But by `adding` a listener you're increasing the number of listeners on the particular widget.

Comment: I have attempted to change this for button and it is under lined in red the view."OnClickListener" part (The part that is in "" is underlined. it's also asking me to convert anonymous to member. HAve you seen this error?

Comment: I'm also unable to understand the error you're stating. If it still persists, could you post a screen shot of it, please?

Comment: This is what I have -

           ButAnsA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v){
               
           }

Comment: It should be `ButAnsA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v){ });`. You're missing the parenthesis and semi colon.

Comment: Still the same error - 

ButAnsA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
    public void onClick(View v){
        
    }
           });

Comment: When ever I hover over the Exclamation mark on the side it says "Cannot find symbol" - "Symbol: class OnClickListener" - "location: class View"

Comment: Sorry, stupid question but how do i post a screenshot. First time asking a question/ using this website.

Comment: That's all right, just `edit` your question and press `Ctrl+G` when in the editor page.

Comment: Ok, i found it. Turns out i need to have a rep of 10 or above to post it.

Comment: Ah, you're not using Eclipse or the auto import feature.

Try this `import android.view.View;`

Comment: I am using netbeans. Why is it an Android Import?

Comment: `View` is a class in the package `view` of the project `android`. `onClickListener` method is a function of the class `View`. Does it work now?

Comment: Sorry, what do I have to change?

Comment: Just add an import statement. `import android.view.View;`

Comment: The quiz game i am making works fine for the first two questions. As soon as it hits the third question it's as if the .setText option does not work at all.

Comment: Archive your project into a .zip file and mail it to torcellite@gmail.com I'll help you out

Answer (score 0):

Your askQues2() method is adding action listeners to ButAnsA 4 times, and no new listeners to the other buttons.

You appear to be adding new listeners to the same buttons with every call, which is generally suboptimal.  Since you said you are reading the questions and possible answers from a file, you'd be better off including which is the right answer in the file and having a single listener for all buttons.

pseudocode:

```
doAction(ActionEvent e)
  int buttoncode=0
  switch (e.getSource())
    case ButAnsA:buttoncode=1;
    case ButAnsB:buttoncode=2;
    case ButAnsC:buttoncode=3;
    case ButAnsD:buttoncode=4;
  if (questions.get(questnum).rightAnswer == buttoncode)
    score++;
  questnum++
  updateQuestionText()
  updateButtonText()
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but I am very new to this. I know this sounds stupid but is there a simpler answer? I appreciate the response but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the code I have slightly to make it work?

Comment: The code, as written is unscalable, since you have to write new code for every question.  Just fixing the askQues2() method to add listeners to all buttons instead of just the first might do it, but you can get weird results because all of the previous action listeners are still there.

Comment: Ok. So with that pseudocode that you posted. Correct me if I'm wrong (which I most likely will be). When one of buttons(ButAnsA, ButAnsB, ButAnsC and ButAnsD) is pressed it checks the question number (quesnumm) and checks whether the right answer is pressed or not and then adds to the score count if correct. Then it goes onto the next question (questnumm++) and updates question(updateQuestion()) and buttons(updateButton()). Is this correct?

Comment: That's the basic idea.  Check the input against the correct input, then update everything to the next question.